# Include in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Suppose I have 3 entities Country , State and City .And Relationship is City->State->Country. Now I have query for Search like

```
 return container.Countries.Include("States.Cities")
.Where(c=>c.States.Sum(s.Population)>10000)
.Search(filter)        
.Skip(startIndex)    
.Take(itemCount)
.ToList();
```

I am Including Cities to all States in above query , But I want to Include it at the end of Query that is after **Take** Method and before **ToList** method.Means Suppose query return 50  records I want to Include Cities to State only for that 50 records not for all States as in above query. Can someOne help how i Can do that ? Any help will be highly appericiable. This is just dummy query and I want to do this for Performance point of view. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you only want 50 states, or do you want all states but only cities for the first 50?

Comment: Can you post the real query? This one doesn't work, because you are writing a `Where` query re: states but you are working with a `Countries` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference where you put `Include` in you query. It is only a behavior modifier, it does not get executed at the moment you see it. As long as you operate on `IQueryable` `Include` will have same effect wherever you put it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you forget to import the `System.Data.Entity` namespace for your code? Look this

[How to use Include() after OfType()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085353/how-to-use-include-after-oftype)

Any way, I think it's all right for your code. ALL the methods before `ToList` will return `IQueryable` or something like that. That means it's lazy evaluation. So whatever the calling order of the methods, you'll get the same performance.