# How to use Include() after OfType()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to eager load properties of a derived class in an Entity Framework model.

I read [all over](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6263369) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2083758) [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189268) that I have to first filter the set with OfType() before including properties with Include():

```
var persons = Context.Persons
                     .OfType<Employee>()
                     .Include("Compensation")
```

I don't know how to get that Include() to work though because in my case, Persons is a DbSet, OfType() returns an IQueryable and IQueryable does not define an Include() method.

Comment: Hope this link help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2130796d-a2fe-4137-af18-d56480748384

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Place this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

into your using's list, and after that you will be able to use `Include` extension methods family from [`DbExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path) where T : class;
    public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string path) where T : class;
    public static IQueryable Include(this IQueryable source, string path);
```

They accept IQueryable as the first argument, and there are strongly-typed ones, too, which is better, then `Include(String)`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I thought it was probably an extension method. I really wish that VS made the namespace discoverable and/or that people included the usings in their samples :)

Comment: @XavierPoinas: completely agree with you, this confused me too first time.

Comment: @XavierPoinas I've been converted to Resharper for this (amongst other) reasons. Resharper will suggest extension methods to fill this missing gap in Visual Studios suggestions in intellisense. Totally agree with you!

Comment: @TheSenator Actually VS 2015 now does that too so I'm pretty happy now :-)

Comment: @XavierPoinas: true. Ultimately, VS will kill R#. :)